# How can I find the intersection of two lists in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, development

Let's say I have two lists in AppleScript:

```
set listA to {"red", "green", "blue"}
set listB to {"green", "blue"}
```

I'd like to create a third list that has **only the items present in both lists**:

```
set listC to intersection of listA and listB --something like this
-- would return {"green", "blue"}
```

Basically, something like PHP's [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

**Is there a built-in way to do this?

If not, I'd love a recommendation for a scripting addition that solves this problem.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [List & Record Tools](http://www.latenightsw.com/freeware/RecordTools/index.html) Scripting Addition provides `intersection of listA and listB` (among other bits of terminology).

There is no built-in “primitive” for computing a list intersection. Usually one would just use one or more loops to check each element of one list against the other. This can be simplied (and sped up<sup>1</sup>) a bit by using one of the `is in`/`is contained by`/`contains` operators (or a negation thereof):

```
set listA to {"red", "green", "blue"}
set listB to {"green", "blue"}

to intersection of listA against listB
    local newList, a
    set newList to {}
    repeat with a in listA
        set a to contents of a -- dereference implicit loop reference
        if {a} is in listB then set end of newList to a
    end repeat
    newList
end intersection

intersection of listA against listB --> {"green", "blue"}
```

<sup>1</sup>The `is in` operator and its relatives are implemented by the AppleScript runtime environment in lower-level code where they execute much faster than the normal interpreted AppleScript code.

---

Incidentally, handlers that use labeled parameters have a limited set of terms that can be used for the labels. For example, `intersection of listA and listB` is not possible as a user-defined handler because `and` is not a recognized label. See the [AppleScript Language Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1) section on [handlers with labeled parameters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH7g-SW2) for a list of valid labels. Applications and OSA extensions can defined their own terminologies (e.g. the List & Record OSAX provides this exact syntax), but user-defined handlers are not as flexible. I usually just use positional parameters (`handlerName(param1, param2, …)`) instead of trying to make invocations of my handlers look like prose.

Comment: Thanks! I had been using the loop method; I was just looking for an easier way. I'm installing that addition now; it looks perfect.